# Does heating body spray break the fast?

Tags: ramadan, islamic-basis

I had been in pain due to my muscle and my body is aching for 2-3 days. I have pain killers after I Iftar but during the fast I cannot focus on work due to pain in the body. There are some heating sprays/rubbing cream that lessen the pain.

My question is if heating spray/rubbing creams break fast as they might enter blood stream?

Answer (score -1):

Allah knows the truth of your heart and intentions.

**My thoughts** concerning suffering during Ramadan, my understanding of Surah Al-Baqarra verse 185, line three ...

“Allah intends for you ease, and does not intend for you hardship, and wants for you to complete the period, and to glorify Allah for that to which he has guided you; and perhaps you will be grateful.”

Allah knows OUR personal needs, our infirmaries, our abilities. While there are options: feeding the poor, or other additional day substitutes, would Allah punish one who faithfully submits to Allah while using modern medicines to relieve pain, so that we might better worship Allah?
Didnt the medicines made from the earth come from Allah to begin with? Isn’t Allah always aware of these things, and has made these cures possible through his interventions with his followers?

Only with Allahs help can we accomplish any of his goals for us.

I pray Im not incorrect in my thoughts or comments. 
Allah wants us to honor and love him with a willing heart, not respond out of fear of retribution which could eventually cause our own withdrawal from Allah.